# How to properly unit-test a linked list (using Python)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, linked-list

I'm new to TDD. I've created all the main functions (insert, search, remove etc.). This is my insert_beginning() function:

```
def insert_beginning(self, node):
    '''
    Inserts a Node to the beginning of the list.
    '''
    node.set_next(self.head)
    self.head = node
```

My question is, how do I properly unit-test this function? The only way I can thing of is:

```
class ListFunctionsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self): 
        self.list1 = LinkedList()
        self.node1 = Node(1)

    def test_insert_beginning(self):
        self.list1.insert_beginning(self.node1)
        self.assertEqual(self.list1.__str__(), "1")
```

but then the test_insert_beginning() function is dependent on my

```
__str__() # string representation of my linked list
```

function. I have a feeling that the way I'm testing it is not correct (because the moment I decide to change the way my linked list is represented, then I'd end up having to rewrite my test cases). Is there a way to test my insert_beginning() function without depending on another function which I created / customized?

Edit: For those wondering, currently, the string representation of my linked list is just a string representation of my nodes separated by commas. For example, a linked list with the nodes 1, 2 and "a" would be represented like this:

```
1, 2, "a"
```

However, I am planning on changing my linked list's string representation (planning on changing the __ str __() function). This is when I realized that the way I am unit testing might be incorrect.

Edit 2 (a comment suggested that I create a function which helps me find the index of an item in the linked list): Assume that a function called index_of(self, item) exists, and this function finds the index of an item. Assume that this is the unit test for the index_of(self, item), and assume that the test cases successfully pass.

```
def test_index_of(self):
    myList = LinkedList()
    node1 = Node(1)
    node2 = Node(2)
    node3 = Node(3)
    myList.head = node1
    node1.next = node2
    node2.next = node3

    self.assertEqual(self.myList.index_of(1), 0)
    self.assertEqual(self.myList.index_of(2), 1)
    self.assertEqual(self.myList.index_of(3), 2)
```

Now, is it okay for me to rely on the index_of(self, item) function to determine if insert_beginning(self, node) is working correctly? In other words, is it okay if my test_insert_beginning() function is:

```
class ListFunctionsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self): 
        self.list1 = LinkedList()
        self.node1 = Node(1)

    def test_insert_beginning(self):
        self.list1.insert_beginning(self.node1)
        self.assertEqual(self.list1.index_of(1), 0)
```

Comment: Do you not have some way to get the data from your linked list? Why not check that? i.e. get the value at the first node and check that it equals 1. Then check the next one and make sure you get an error.

Comment: I imagine what would happen if the lines of code didn't exist, or did something different. How can you detect that?

Comment: @Quirliom so I'd have to create a function which gets the node at index x, and then in my test_insert_beginning() function, I'd have to call that function and verify that index 0 is in fact what was inserted? I'll try to create that function (and a unit test for that function) now and see if it works.

Comment: Yup. The only thing you can control is the data you add, so that's the only thing you can reliably check.

Comment: @Quirliom ah, okay. So I edited my post (can you look at the Edit 2 section of my post?). I'm wondering if the new way (the way I mentioned under the Edit 2 section) is okay, even though I rely on another function which also requires unit-testing?

Comment: Something I notice is that your methods seem to expose the `Node`s rather than working with the values themselves. A well encapsulated linked list will not make the caller think about nodes. Callers don't care about the nodes; they care about the values. Nodes are an implementation detail.

Comment: @jpmc26 hm, I'm a bit confused. Can you give an example of how my methods expose the Node's rather than working with the values? And an example of how I can improve it to make it a well encapsulated linked list which will not make the callers (and what exactly is a "caller" in this case?)  think about the nodes?

From my understand, what you mean is, rather than doing "self.assertEqual(self.list1.index_of(1), 0)", I should do "self.assertEqual(self.list1.head.next, 0)"? Or did I incorrectly interpret what you mentioned?

Comment: Your method is `def insert_beginning(self, node):`, which clearly takes a node as an argument. Creating the `Node` object is something the calling code should not have to do; it's an implementation detail of the list. The method should be `def insert_beginning(self, element):`, and wrapping the element in a node would be internal to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a good point. You don't want to tie yourself to an arbitrary String representation of the list, which will probably change. The "proper" way to check this would be to check the *values* in the list. I.e., instead of checking the string representation, you should check all your post conditions seperatly:

- The first value is 1
- The previous value doesn't exist (Does whatever you want to happen on error)
- The next value does the same as the previous value
- The size is 1
- ...

  Of course for the methods that support this you will have to have separate unit tests.

Comment: @Quirlom Oh! So basically, I check if self.list1.head==self.node1. And then check if self.list1.head.next==None. That way, I verify that node1 is in fact the first value (and only value, because I'm currently just creating a singly linked list so I don't think I need to check the previous value). I also don't have to rely on another function this way. Awesome, thanks. On a side note, even though you provided the correct answer already, can you still check the "Edit 2" section of my post and see if the solution I came up with is correct as well?

Comment: @user2719875 Looks fine :)